# Who should own Dependency Injected objects in iOS apps?

Tags: objective-c, dependency-injection

This is probably a fundamental question for an experienced iOS developer, but coming from a Java background where we have lots of Dependency Injection (DI) goodies (i.e., Spring) I'm having some trouble figuring out who should own the DI objects.  Unfortunately, I find myself creating a bunch of Singletons which is becoming pretty nasty to manage.

For instance, we have some `Configuration` that other classes would like access to.  Currently we just have a singleton instance for Configuration, which makes testing a bit difficult.  Technically, we overcome this problem using method swizzling in OCMock.

In Java/Spring, there's some container that creates/owns these objects.  In iOS, I think the closest things I have to a container are UIApplication and UIApplicationDelegate.  Does it make sense for these things to create/own these objects that will ultimately get injected into other objects?

If so, what is an appropriate strategy to access these objects?  For instance, create a category on UIApplication or UIApplicationDelegate to access these objects like:
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] configuration]` or `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] configuration]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed DI doesn't seem to be something that people normally use in iOS, like we do in Java or C#.

Personally, i tend to create my own singleton called Application, that holds all the services and information for the application. This way I get the simplicity of a simple singleton, without being attached to iOS specifically (even though obj-c can't really be used almost anywhere else). So in my apps I usually have:

```
[[Application sharedInstance] configuration]
[[Application sharedInstance] authService]
```

So the only class that needs to be a singleton is the Application one (unrelated to UIApplication), and it creates all the services in the init method.

Comment: Can I assume that you also have setters to facilitate unit testing?

Comment: Yes. I don't make the classes real singletons though, I just create the shared instance used for the app. If other parts of the app wanted, they could create a new object of type Application, but I simply never do it outside of unit tests.

Comment: I also favor not adding such behavior to `UIApplicationDelegate` because it makes any classes which depend on that behavior difficult to reuse in other applications, including running them in many third party testing tools where the application delegate is the test runner.
I prefer a distinct class to act as a DI container or just passing dependencies via constructors when possible.

Answer (score 5):

I'm beginning my evaluation of an Objective-C DI framework called [Objection](https://github.com/atomicobject/objection). It's inspired by [Google Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) for Java.

### Example Usage from Objection's [README](https://github.com/atomicobject/objection#readme)

```
@class Engine, Brakes;

@interface Car : NSObject
{
  Engine *engine;
  Brakes *brakes;
  BOOL awake;  
}

// Will be filled in by objection
@property(nonatomic, retain) Engine *engine;
// Will be filled in by objection
@property(nonatomic, retain) Brakes *brakes;
@property(nonatomic) BOOL awake;

@implementation Car
objection_register(Car)
objection_requires(@"engine", @"brakes")
@synthesize engine, brakes, awake;
@end
```

Comment: Any comments on Objection? I'm finding it a bit hard to understand.

Comment: What, specifically, is difficult to understand? I'm not being snarky. I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: My impression of it so far has been pretty good. The major shortcoming is that when using storyboards, you cannot easily inject the ViewController as a delegate into some of your objects because the lifecycle of the ViewController object is controlled by the storyboard, not Objection. In my view, this keeps Objection from being as useful as it could be. See this issue: https://github.com/atomicobject/objection/issues/44